# one node process for 2 or more different web page

Tags: node.js

I am starting using nodejs. To date I can open a web page index.html using an app.js node application.

Example from  http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/node-js/making-a-simple-http-server-with-node-js-part-ii/  :

```
//step 1) require the modules we need
var
http = require('http'),//helps with http methods
path = require('path'),//helps with file paths
fs = require('fs');//helps with file system tasks

//a helper function to handle HTTP requests
function requestHandler(req, res) {
    var
    content = '',
    fileName = path.basename(req.url),//the file that was requested
    localFolder = __dirname + '/public/';//where our public files are located

    //NOTE: __dirname returns the root folder that
    //this javascript file is in.

    if(fileName === 'index.html'){//if index.html was requested...
        content = localFolder + fileName;//setup the file name to be returned

        //reads the file referenced by 'content'
        //and then calls the anonymous function we pass in
        fs.readFile(content,function(err,contents){
            //if the fileRead was successful...
            if(!err){
                //send the contents of index.html
                //and then close the request
                res.end(contents);
            } else {
                //otherwise, let us inspect the eror
                //in the console
                console.dir(err);
            };
        });
    } else {
        //if the file was not found, set a 404 header...
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        //send a custom 'file not found' message
        //and then close the request
        res.end('<h1>Sorry, the page you are looking for cannot be found.</h1>');
    };
};

//step 2) create the server
http.createServer(requestHandler)

//step 3) listen for an HTTP request on port 3000
.listen(3000);
```

But I don't know if it is possible to open different web pages that will use the same app.js. It has to be possible.But how to modify the code above?

Problem:

how to modify the code above to use app.js able to open index.html and other page web `index2.html`?. The content of index.html is different from `index2.html` but both use the same `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

You will need a routing system to route different requests to different handlers. There are some node modules that provide you this functionality. Some of them are: [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), and [Restify.js](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/)

Comment: thaks.... I think adding to the code an else if:

    }else if(fileName === 'index2.html'){
    };
   It works